# Order the rows by date AND maximum number of hours per day - groupby function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a below df.

[image]

Now I need to produce the below result that displays the number of rows in the order of the maximum number of hours groupby date.

[image]

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name 
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

With the above SQL, this can be achieved. However, I would like to know how to write this code in python.

Comment: Check sort_values

Comment: @Wen-Ben Could you please give an example for sort_values?

Comment: df.sort_values(['Date','no_hours'],ascending=[True,False])